# BR not working with XML / jQuery / replace

Tags: jquery, xml, replace

I have an XML file that stores a bunch of stuff, including the page number of a reference book.  If there are multiple pages, they are separated with a slash like this:

```
<WeaponPage>119/120</WeaponPage>
```

I then use jQuery to populate this data in a fancy anchor hover to show the data when the user hovers over the hyperlink.  No problem so far.  The HTML that gets loaded looks like this:

```
<td><span id="weaponPage2" name="weaponPage2"></span></td>
```

The jQuery looks like this:

```
$("#weaponPage"+person).text(WeaponsArray[xx1][23].replace("/","<br>"));
```

For some strange reason, the data is being rendered as 119<br>120.  It is actually *showing* the break tag and not rendering it as a break!  If I comment out the jQuery and hard-code the data in the HTML, it works just fine, but obviously, that is for debugging only.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead

```
$("#weaponPage"+person).html(WeaponsArray[xx1][23].replace("/","<br>"));
```

since [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) will render it as a text and ignore html content